# How to make Hapi work with templates in nested folders?

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, vision, pug

I have two folders inside `templates` folder and files inside:

- templates

  - loggedout
    | - index.pug
  - loggedin
    | - index.pug

I can make the engine find files inside one, or another folder, but not two at once:

```
    server.views({
        engines: {
            pug: require('pug')
        },
        relativeTo: __dirname,
        path: './templates/loggedin'
        // path: './templates/loggedout'
    });
```

I want to show index page for loggedin or loggedout users from the respective folder.

If I run `reply.view('index')`, it expectedly doesn't find the template and shows a clear error about it.

If I use `reply.view('loggedout/index')` or `reply.view('loggedin/index')`, it shows error 500 without showing details of the error.

How do I make it work with templates inside folders?

Answer (score 0):

change your path config to the template root folder as in:

```
server.views({
    engines: {
        pug: require('pug')
    },
    relativeTo: __dirname,
    path: 'templates' //note the missing ./ at the beginning 
});
```

now you can use your both temples

```
reply.view('loggedout/index')
//or
reply.view('loggedin/index')
```